# Having a character appear repeated times in an array and score counts.

Tags: c, arrays

**This is  for Homework

I have a project coming up (A game of scrabble) and I have a couple questions. In scrabble certain letters can only appear a certain number of times. EX: E has an occurrence of 12, A has an occurrence of 9, ect. My first question is how would I make this possible without creating a gigantic array. So instead of

```
 char arr['A' , 'A' , 'A'.....]
```

how would I just type

```
char arr['A' , 'B' , 'C']
```

(Type every letter once then somehow set a frequency for each letter.

My second question is how would I create a score counter for the program. In scrabble there are letters that have score values. I figured one way was to loop a ton of switch statements, but I was wondering if there's a more efficient way to do it.

I don't need any code made for me because that would take away from the whole point of learning programming, but examples would be appreciated or even an explanation of more efficient ways to create letter frequencies and score calculators. I figure that if I figure out how to do these things efficiently this early on, It would help me in the future.

Thanks for any help!

This code will have to be written in C

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay the thing is first answer is seemingly easy if you think of using the ascii value.

What if I say that use the ASCII value as an index to an array. Any idea came?

Wait I will hint a bit more. `A` = `65`...That means you can easily map to `A` using the index value 65 in your array.

Now you may wonder that for this you need a large array? Nope. Just use the offset appropriately. So now you think `65`->`A`->`0` then `66`->`B`->`1`.

---

Second question:

Yes you can use an array here also the same way. If you need to store more data than just a score you can use array of structures. That will let you store other data also along with scores.

---

Things that may help you?

You can store the frequency of occurrences of characters by just incrementing the frequency array at correct position.

Design the code so that you understand where you store scores and how you handle it. Try to keep the scores in an array and or array of structures and manipulate them when needed.

To get a good design idea you can challenge yourself to store the game logic and game playing in different modules and interact with them accordingly.

**Clarification**

Suppose this is a char array.

```
char s[] = "ABCD";
for(int i = 0; i<4;i++)
  Frequency[s[i]-'A']++;
```

This way here we are basically converting ascii value to an index of array. Here instead of directly using 65 I have subtracted that value so that every frequency is stored from index position `0`.

Comment: I kind of understand what you're saying. I know what ASCII is, but could you clarify "Map A to index value of 65", I'm not entirely sure what that means and what would be the point of using ASCII values as apposed to normal characters.

Comment: @chrisHG.: Yes wait let me modify the answer..with a section **Clarification**

Comment: @chrisHG.: Now check..do you understand what i mean?

Comment: Okay so correct if i'm wrong, but the for loop is going through every letter in the char array correct? But what does the third line of code do, more specifically [s[i]. does that store all all letters from the char s[] array then subtract A to store in index position 0. Does that mean it would go 

A-A=0

B-A=1

C-A=2

ect.

(What does that do for the program?)

And what does the increment do to frequency in the program?

Comment: @chrisHG.: `s` is strong all the responses. Now you need to know what character appears how many of the times right? That is what is done in the third line. it is basically looking at an character and incrementing the value corresponding to it's index. That way you can store the frequency of occurence of letters.

Comment: So would it be possible to create multiple arrays for this program. One array to store the letters. Another array storing frequencies of letters. And a last array storing scores. so

chars[] = "ABCD" 


frequency[] = Use ASCII equation to set up frequencies

score[] = 1 , 3 , 3 , 2 (Scores from scrabble)

Then set up for loops to go through each array and use equations to calculate scores?

Comment: @chrisHG.: Yes exactly...that s the point. You got it right.

Comment: okay so I understand everything but the frequency. Would I store the frequency of the letters in a separate array then use the equation you provided and then using the ascii-number conversion, the index would correlate to the frequency array?

Comment: frequency array is simply how many times a letter appears.@chrisHG

Answer (score 0):

If you consider that a character like `A` is actually an integral value representing the ASCII-Code of `A` (which is `65` in this case), then you could use this ASCII-value to index an integer array holding the maximum value for the specific letter (and the same for the actual count). See the following code illustrating this. Hope it helps:

```
int main() {

    // ASCII, assuming character st A B C D E F, ...
    char maxOccurrences[256]= { 12, 3, 4, 5, 9, 1 }; // ...
    char actualOccurrences[256] = { 0 };

    char *testInput = "AAABBBBCDEEEFF";
    for(char *p=testInput;*p;p++) {
        int charIndex = *p - 'A';
        if (charIndex < 0 || charIndex > 26) {
            printf("invalid character %c.\n", *p);
        }
        else if (actualOccurrences[charIndex] >= maxOccurrences[charIndex]) {
            printf("maximum of %d for %c reached.\n",maxOccurrences[charIndex], *p);
        }
        else {
            actualOccurrences[charIndex]++;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For the first question: Since you know there are exactly 27 different tiles in Scrabble (counting blanks), you can store just the frequency of each letter in an array of length 27.

For the second, you can take a similar approach and store the score of each letter in a constant array.

You then need to map each letter to the appropriate index, e.g. `A` should map to `0`, `B` to `1`, etc.; a clever way to do this would be to cast the character as an integer and subtract the appropriate amount.

So the second would work roughly like this, to score `a = ['w','o','r',d']`:

```
s = 0
First iteration: index of 'w' is 23, so
                 s += letter_scores[22]
                 letter_freqs[22] -= 1
Second iteration... and so on
```

Comment: How would you make it so each array would have an affect on the other? Meaning if the user would to press A, the array would give back a score of 1.

Comment: `'A'` would be assigned the index `0` (a detail: perhaps it would be nicer to assign the blank to 0, and A-Z to 1-26, but this is minor), so you'll get the score from `letter_score[0]`, which you would have set to `1` earlier on.

Comment: If you meant to ask how to assign `'A'` to `0`, the other answers have provided a neat solution: do `int('A') - 65`